# How can I achieve sequin glitter material like shining disco ball?

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, materials

How can I achieve material like the one in the castle? It looks like glitters, Sequin, led dots. I don't know to be exact.

Also, I want to make subtle animation on it like random shine over time

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: hello are you talking about the mirror balls or about the spots with their beams?

Comment: The material on the castle

Comment: Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this - if you are using EEVEE, remember to change the Blend Mode to Alpha Blend (Right side). *Backface culling* and/or *Show Backface* are optional - I showed an example with backface cullling  off and on - it may require a bit of tweaking of the colorramp with it off, because there are double the amount of "flakes". Also, if using eevee, don't forget to enable "Bloom" to get the glow effect. If you are using Cycles, you will have to add the glow afterwards in the compositior with a *Glare* Node.

Show Backface off
[image: Castle1]

Show Backface on
[image: Castle2]

If you want to animate it, there are 2 ways I can think of. First, if you want the "glitter " itself to move, you can use the setup below, either using the mapping node to move the glitter "downwards", or by using a 4D Voronoi texture and animating the W, or both. Either way, the movement is driven by a *Value* node, with *#frame* written in the value box (to make the value equal to the current frame at all times).

[image: CastleAnimate]

The second way, is to change the brightness of each piece of glitter, by "dragging" a noise texture across it, making random areas brighter and dimmer as it passes. Value node works the same way as the above example.

[image: Castimate2]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: how to keep the transparency in cycles ?